# Need to iterate initial values in django choice field in template

Tags: python, django

I'm able to iterate the choices in django forms choice field. But I need to mark select in the multiple select widget.
Please view the below code

```
<select name="project-team" id="search" class="form-control" size="12" multiple="multiple">
{% for value, text  in form.project_team.field.choices  %}
<option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Whats the *exact* problem you are having?

Comment: I need to customize this field. Need to integrate two side multiple select widget.
http://crlcu.github.io/multiselect/#sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my question

> {{ form.fields.project_team.initial }} (or)
>
> {{ form.project_team.field.initial }}

Both ways works for me. form.project_team.field.initial returns the initial values as list which we could iterate.